# How to solve [error_message] => Entity declaration references invalid or inactive module name

Tags: extension

I get this
`[error_message] => Entity declaration references invalid or inactive module name [name_of_extension]`

When trying to run:
`cv ext:upgrade-db`

It's an extension I don't recognize - but yeah it does not exist for this site.

It's not in `civicrm_extension` - it's not not in `civicrm_managed`. Where do I need to look to find this and strip it?

Answer (score 1):

Ok - I went the long way around -> used civix to generate an extension of that name -> then pulled it into the site's extensions dir -> and installed it.

Now I can run `cv ext:upgrade-db` and execute much needed extension updates